# new in using XCode Instruments to interpret memory warning for iPhone development, guidance needed

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, xcode-instruments

I am working on an iPhone game which receives memory warning that I am not experienced enough to interpret. I have been watching some iTunesU tutorial but I am still not very good at this..

I have received various memory leaks whilst running my game and I wanted to understand how to interpret the stack trace show in Instruments properly.

I attach a screenshot of the ObjectAllocation instrument output [image: instruments output]  . Even when I zoom filter I don't manage to filter the data in the ObjectSummary [image: see this screenshot].

The peaks in memory usage in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4oT1.png) happen when the GameScene is initialized and all the data is loaded (ParallaxBackground, CCSpriteBatchNode) and Sprites and bullets frames are created (in an CCArray of spriteFrames).

The big blue peak is just at load time but the app freezes and then crashes only after a while and from the graph I see that the memory usage (blue bar) has gone down.. so I don't quiet get that. Also, whenver I try to use the leaks instrument the App crashes..

I know is a very silly question for someone experienced, but I just need some extra help getting started with this toolset.

**I think the memory problem are due to the sprites I allocate in sprite cache classes, but I am not sure on this and hence wanted to investigate this using Instruments but can't find out how to see what is the object causing the memory warning and how to access the stack trace..**

PS: I am running on an iPod 4th generatio and I am using Cocos2D as library

EDIT: I do not also understand why if the Live Bytes are only 1.01 MB the App crashes and why I still receive a memory warning (see black flags). Is it due to some pointer referencing to some null variable or due to an excessive memory allocation? 1.01 MB doesn't seem much to me..

**EDIT 2: Following Marion's advice I used the Activity Monitor and realized that the effective real memory usage is 55.39 MB. I misinterpreted the "live bytes" word. I will try to dig into this further and will leave the question as unaccepted for now to allow other people contribute. If I won't have any other answer within one-two days I'll mark as accepted the current answer. Thanks!**

[image: Activity Monitor]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find leaks, use Leaks instrument instead of Allocations. To find out, how much memory use at the moment, use ActivityMonitor.

If you will have problems with memory in cocos2d, you can try to purge cache. In cocos2d you can purge `CCTextureCache`, `CCSpriteFrameCache`, `CCAnimationCache`. It will release unused textures and frames.

If you want to check if all of unnessesary textures were removed from memory, you can place breakpoint to `CCTextureCache` class and call, for example, `sharedTextureCache` and look throw the content of textures_ dictionary. Or add some method to this class to be able to dump current state of cache.

Comment: CCTextureCache already has a -(void) dumpCachedTextureInfo{} method, very handy. Also, if you are purging unusedTextures, make certain you purge unusedSpriteFrames from the CCSpriteFrameCache beforehand, since they could refer the textures.

Comment: oh, perhaps, I've used an old version of cocos2d, because I had to add dump method by myself =)

Comment: well, that little do hickie really helped me out (in the absence of OBVIOUS leaks - those instruments and Analyse find all by themselves). Not every memory issue turns out to be leak, but managing the current memory footprint can be a real daunting task.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thank you for your contribution and Marion thank you for your answer. I am playing with those methods and trying to find the right location to call them. I will post some updates soon. Also, I still haven't understood how to inspect the memory with Instruments properly and why when I run the memory leaks app on the real device it won't even start the scene (also running just the Object Allocation instrument does make the app crashing earlier, and I guess is due to some extra memory process lunched by Instruments on the device).. will watch again the tutorial and post soon! Thanks..

Comment: PS: I added an edit with a doubt regarding the Live bytes.. would be possible for some of you to comment on this? Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: check memory usage with Activity Monitor instrument, not allocations.

Comment: Ok I will.. I just tried to remove the unused sprites and texture (I have one sprite sheet loaded in the texture cache).. unfortunately I am using an animation at fire event and if I remove the unsued sprites and texture before this the app will crash as won't find the sprite frame in the CCSpriteFrameCache. Hence I am confused on how to remove only the sprite frame of the sprites-animation that have been already allocated and not the one that have yet to be. Is this impossible to overcome with using one texture cache or shall I remove each single spriteframe manually? Thanks!

Comment: hmm... strange. if you use only one atlas, even 2048x2048 pixels, it cannot take more than 16MB of memory. it is not enough to receive even the first level memory warning. usually you should purge cache only if you want to be sure, that unused textures was unloaded.

Comment: @Marion I use a texture sprite sheet-atlas (2048*2048) for all the GameScene elements such as characters, bullets and icons, and 2 more in the ParallaxBackground child of GameScene class which has 7 background sprites. In this 2nd class I remove the SpriteFramesFromFile after having created all Sprites (  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"bottom.plist"];) as well as removing each TextureForKey after each sprite initialization ([[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTextureForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bottom%i.png", i]];). Shall I share code?

Comment: PS: I added a second EDIT which I think reflects this.. So if I have 3 sprite sheets (sorry for saying 1 before, but I thought that the removal I do was enough) then I should have about 48MB of memory maximum.. does this make sense? I don't quiet know how to compute it but I assume if 1 is 16MB then 3 is 48MB. The thing is that 2.048*2.048 is aroud 4.194.304 which I am not able to relate to 16MB.. sorry for the confusion.. :(

Comment: Either it is your textures causing an issue, or some other class is running wild. Try to sneak in a [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo] before the app crashes, it will log for you the details of which textures are currently in the cache, and how much memory each one consumes, hopefully before the crash. Before you start, kill all processes that could be in the background. Honestly, you should be able to run an app with much more than 55Mb on an iPhone 4.

Comment: actually, even 90-100 Mb are possible(for retina device). Such amount of resources will cause memory warnings, but your app will work fine on all retina devices.

Comment: @IvesLeBorg thank you. I will try (I am writing some ad-hoc test cases which I will share in few hours). So, if both you and Marion suggest that 55MB shouldn't be too much then maybe the problem is somewhere else? I am thinking about pointers to null variables as I am using Bullet-Enemy cache classes.. I will rewrite all step by step monitoring the real memory usage and memory warnings: 1 app with only parallax background 2: add background 3: add bullets.. what do you guys do when you receive a memory warning? how do you deal with adding enemies at run time? do u preallocate (cache) or not?

Comment: @IvesLeBorg I added a new question on SO relating to real memory usage.. is a very long, but if you have time could you have a look? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042668/cocos2d-and-iphone-parallax-background-with-multiple-texture-atlases-performanc

Comment: @Morion as said to IvesLeBorg, I added a new question on SO relating to real memory usage but is very long.. if you have time could you have a look? Thanks a lot and sorry for the multiple comments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042668/cocos2d-and-iphone-parallax-background-with-multiple-texture-atlases-performanc