# Cocos2d and iPhone: Parallax Background with multiple texture atlases gives many memory warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, cocos2d-iphone, background-image

The problem I am trying to solve is:

I have 6 stripes which I need to move at different speed. A texture sheet of 2048*2048 is not enough and to deal with this I splitted the image in two (top and bottom half), so each stripe is exactly 960*640pixels. The general algorithm is to allocate a top and bottom half for each stripe and move them at each frame making sure to reposition them at the top of the screen when they exit the user's view. My class implementation, a direct modification of [ParallaxBackground in the ShootEmUp example from this book](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039/), is giving too many memory warnings when run and analyzed using Instruments. See analysis below:

OpenGL analysis:
[image: OpenGL analysis]

Activity monitor:
[image: Activity Monitor analysis]

What concerns me is the high number of memory warnings in both analysis (24 and 5 respectively).

**EDIT: Below you can find a comment which explains the solution**

Comment: PS: Sorry in advance for the length of this question.. I will revise it tomorrow trying to reduce the size..

Comment: You might want to try rebooting your device. If it has been running for a long time, any memory leaks inside iOS and many spawned processes can reduce the available memory.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks a milion! It did work by rebooting the device and now I am not getting memory warnings anymore, do you want to add your comment as answer and I'll accept it straight away?

Comment: @mm24 : still beware of this, you will not have the luxury of rebooting your customer's devices when the game is running on their devices. Look at options to reduce memory consumption, and manage your textures to have a 'just in time' load strategy wherever possible (ie when the loading and initial display does not induce a cognitive disconnect, or a perceivable lag in an untimely situation).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: wow, thanks for that comment. Although rebooting has become par for course with regards to perceived Xcode or simulator lagginess, i had not 'generously' extended my standard operating procedures to the device :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thanks for your comment.. I am starting to rewrite the class having the bullet and enemies cache and to reduce the number of allocation my approach will be to reposition (and reset their hit points in the enemy case) after they disappeared from the scene. Do you recon my Parallax Background approach could be easily improved? Shall I repost the code? Thanks!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D will leave the question as unaswered till Monday afternoon and then, if you don't add your comment as answer I'll do it for completeness and mention that is your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment-suggestion to my question by LearnCocos2d the correct answer-solution was to simply reboot the device.. (see his comment above).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

2048x2048 is maximum possible size of texture for new devices. you can read about it in [Apple OpenGL ES Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

Comment: Ok, so using CCBigImage is not an option here? Shall I stick to multiple texture atlases as in Ref 1 and Ref 2?

Comment: PS: Does "The maximum 2D texture size is 2048 x 2048. This is also the maximum renderbuffer size and viewport size." mean that if I use more than one texture atlas (e.g. Ref 1 and Ref 2) the renderbuffer will not have enough memory space and hence performance will be affected?

Comment: I leave the question as unaccepted for now to see if anyone contributes as I have still not understood if I can use more than one texture sheet at a time.. I will study this and the guide you linked and if by doing so I find the answer  I'll mark as accepted.. thanks and sorry for this (possibly stupidly long question). I want also to find out if there is or not any difference in using CCSpriteBatch nodes (see Ref 1 vs Ref 2 performance analysis - not much difference from what I can see - but I might not be conisdering triangles randered and other OpenGL peformance params).

Comment: you can use several atlases at the same time. usually you can load into memory 5 atlases with 2048x2048 dimensions to have stable working application without crashes because of not enough memory(of course, I mean retina devices)

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is a useful information and contribution. Do you have any glue on why I am getting so many memory warnings in Ref 1 and Ref 2? Shall I share more code? The test are on a ad-hoc project I created from scratch adding to the HelloWorld template an instance of the modified Parallax Background class..

Comment: it is strange that you get memory warnings, when the screens shows only about 45Mb of memory used. Usually, even with memory warnings, app works stable with about 90Mb of memory used.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment.. I added the source code of Ref2 so if you, or someone else, has time and will could test the App yourself on the blank HelloWorld Cocos2d template.. all you need is a file with 6 stripes (960*640 pixels) and if you like you can use the same file for both top and bottom plst.. it would help immensely if you could test it out

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Cocos2D always saves images with a width/height being a power of 2. So if your image is 960x640 pixels it'll use memory as if the image is 1024x1024 pixels.

Also remove textures you no longer need (and when outofmemory gets called).

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

You can also use images in a lower quality to save memory.

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
```

Whenever you need to load higher quality images or gradients you can put it back.

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```