# My console shows did receive memory and crashes the app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My console shows did "receive `memory warning"`and crashes the app. I have done `profiling,` but I didn't found memory leaks?

Comment: Memory leaks != excessive memory consumption. You can fill the available RAM without leaking a single bit.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[Why not run Xcode instruments with the memory allocations template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001088/new-in-using-xcode-instruments-to-interpret-memory-warning-for-iphone-developmen) and see how fast your memory is being eaten up.

[Here's Apple's documentation to get you started](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html).

Does your application use a lot of images, by chance?

Comment: No i dont use lot of images but i have a database which is off more than 40mb